# Can't import CV2 in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I have install cv2 library but I can't import it to my jupyter notebook.

this is how I installed it:

```
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} opencv
```

```
import cv2
>>>
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to install libGL but still got that error. Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using conda, try using the `pip` formula, which is specifically built for the Python ecosystem, place this in a separate cell and run it:

`!pip install opencv-python`

... or if you want to use non-free modules:

`!pip install opencv-contrib-python`